# Alias for table

Tags: yii2, yii2-advanced-app

I have two tables. The first - Product, the second - Category. They contain fields with the same name - 'name'.
In model Product I added following code:

```
public function getCategory(){
   return $this->hasOne(Category::className(), ['id' => 'cat_id']);
}
```

I need to show in GridView the column from table Category. I added following code for this in the model ProductSearch:

```
$query->joinWith(['category' => function($query) { $query->from(['cat' => 'category']); }]);
```

This code adds the alias cat for the table Category.

After that I got an error:

```
SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1052 Column 'name' in where clause is ambiguous
The SQL being executed was: SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `product` LEFT JOIN `category` `cat` ON `product`.`cat_id` = `cat`.`id` WHERE `name` LIKE '%aasdadadsdgdgdg%'
Error Info: Array
(
[0] => 23000
[1] => 1052
[2] => Column 'name' in where clause is ambiguous
)
```

How can I add the alias for the table Product?

Comment: This error comes from `where` condition - you didn't share how you defined it.

Comment: Where do you filter by name? Add `Product::tableName() . '.name'` instead of `name` there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Open your `ProductSearch` model, navigate to the `search($params)` method. Below you should see the filtration part:

```
$query->andFilterWhere(['like', 'name', $this->name])
```

fix the ambigous part by writing table name `product` to that line.

```
$query->andFilterWhere(['like', 'product.name', $this->name])
```

or..

```
$query->andFilterWhere(['like', self::tableName() . '.name', $this->name])
```

This'll giving precise info that name should be queried from `product.name` table.
The interesting part is that you don't get the error until you join the `Category` table.

Imho, it's the worst to find this errors as it seems like everything is working, until search functionality is used.

Comment: another approach is `{{%tableName}}.[[column_name]]` format which assures the column name are within `[[]]` and tablename within `{{}}` and the `%` appends any prefix if added in the config for the database connection.